# ASP.NET MVC form post parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a form in MVC:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Get", "Person"))
  { %>
      <%= Html.TextBox("person_id")%>
      <input type="submit" value="Get Person" />
  <% } %>
```

This redirects me to `Person/Get`. Okay. The question:

How do I make this Form so it redirects me to `Person/Get/{person_id}`?

**Edit:**

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Get", "Person", new { id = ??? }))
  { %>
      <%= Html.TextBox("person_id")%>
      <input type="submit" value="Get Person" />
  <% } %>
```

What do I write in `???`

Comment: Regarding "???"; you can't do that because id is not known at server time.

Comment: @CarlR I want to get the **text from the textbox** in `???`. Why is it so hard to understand my question? This should be easy, but I will accept your answer if this can't be done.

Comment: The text in the textbox is entered by the user right? The closest you can get is by changeing the BeginForm to recieve a FormMethod.Get. That way what is sent to the server would be /Person/Get?person_id=234 or whatever the user enters. The other thing you could do is intercept the submit event using jquery and read the person_id from javascript and then alter the adress before submitting. I wouldn't go that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most difficult way would be using a javascript clientside.

The more straightforward way is to retrieve it on the action `Person/Get` and from there return a RedirectResult pointing to `Person/Get/{person_id}`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Get(string person_id)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Get", "Person", new { id = person_id });
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Get(string id)
{
     //Do your thing
}
```

The redirect is usually so fast that the user will never notice. He/she will arrive at /Person/Get/{person_id}

Comment: I solved my problem this way, but I needed some other name for this Get (because you can't overload just by renaming the parameter)

Comment: I thought the post and get attributes would be enough. Thanks for letting me know! :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is specify the route values as the third parameter on the BeginForm method.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Get", "Person", **new { person_id = this.Model}**))
{ %>
   <%= Html.TextBox("person_id")%>
   <input type="submit" value="Get Person" />
<% } %>
```

Then your controller action would look something like this

```
public ActionResult Get(int person_id)
{
    return View(person_id);            
}
```